# android studio cannot find java.nio.file

Tags: java, android-studio

Project Structure-->SDK location shows /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home

the project structure view shows jdk 1.7.  I see java.nio.file when I expand the packages, but

import java.nio.file can't be found even after rebuilding.  java.io.Reader is found by the editor.

Comment: The auto import does not recognize the jdk, for example, autoimporting something like "Path p;" gives the "android.graphics.Path" instead of "java.nio.file.Path".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think this has something to do with the android sdk not allowing this.  I have the sdk and the jdk listed in Project view-->"External Libraries"